# How to send server request via client network?

Tags: android, networking, mobile

The app I developed need send request from my server to a 3rd party server. Normally, it will be like send a init request from a client (Android mobile phone) to my server, then send a request from my server to 3rd party server, wait for response, finally response to client from my server. But due to IP geo restriction, send it directly from my server won't work. It is required to send the request from the client network. And due to the request method changed very frequently and it's very complicated (parsing a lot of websites), I have to deploy it on a server rather than the app. So is it possible to send a request from my server, via client network, to the 3rd party server? How? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I was understood correctly you want to use your client network (application user) as a proxy for your server network to solve the IP restriction. It's something like reverse VPN . I think it's not a good approach because you can simply use a proxy in the server machine to handle IP or other issues.

Or the easiest one, You can send URLs and parameters to the client side then client can send the request and after receiving response from 3rd party, send back to your server. But this isn't an optimized way at all.

Comment: Yeah I understand it's not a good approach. The thing is use proxy on my server is not feasible. And it's not just about URLs and paramaters, there are a lot of things to handle. It's parsing a lot of websites, every sites has its own parsing method.